# Can String contain <0x00> along with assigned values in java

Tags: java, string

If I declare one string, is there any possibility that the string can contain `<0x00>` along with assigned data ?

For instance :

```
String s = "Stack";
```

Can the string result come as :

> Stack<0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00>

Comment: yes: `String s = "Stack<0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00>";`

Comment: That sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: What did you mean?

Comment: Thanks for the update @jhamon, I had few queries regarding the same.                                                       1) If i create a file using PrintStream with same string, in the created file I will see  " Stack<0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00> " ?                                                                                      2) How can i avoid writing those in file?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as:

```
String s = "Stack\u0000\u000";
```

This in contrast to C/C++ where strings are terminated by a `'\0'` char.

If a String must be passed as byte array to native code, there java has a trick available for UTF-8,
a modified UTF-8 that also turns `'\u0000'` into a multi-byte sequence: [`DataOutputStream.writeUTF(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeUTF(java.lang.String))

Note that `\u0000` (as some other control chars) is not allowed in XML.

By the way the 0 string terminator is deemed by its inventor as the greatest mistake in C. It also influenced processor instruction sets.

Comment: Thanks for the update @Joop Eggen, I had few queries regarding the same. 1) If i create a file using PrintStream with same string, in the created file I will see " Stack<0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00> " ? 2) How can i avoid writing those <0x00> in created file ?

Comment: `new PrintStream(new YourOutputStream(...));` - writing your own FilterOutputStream not passing `<0x00>`. Also `string.trim()` would remove trailing control chars.